# How to change the color of a button and its text, from partial view to a normal view?

Tags: javascript, html, button, model-view-controller, partial-views

*Good afternoon programmers!* Excuse me I’m trying to change the color and the text of a button of my problem is as follows:

In a view several courses are displayed, when you click on the preregister button of some of them shows me a modal and inside this a form that is in a partial view, when you click OK you must change the color to blue and the text to "Cancel" of the General view. How could I do this?

**Here is my foreach button found in the overview:**

```
<button type="button" class="boton botonUno btnPreinscribir"id="myButtonChangeF" value="Preinscribirse" title="Preinscribirse" data-url="@Url.Action("PreinscripcionNumCurso","Inicio")" data-id="@ingles.Num" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static">Preinscribir</button>
```

**This is my form that’s in the partial view:**

```
@model MultipleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/VentanasParciales.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/FormStyle.css">

<!-- Modal Preinscripción-->

<form class="formulario" asp-controller="Inicio" asp-action="Editar"  id="Editarform">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Preinscripción</legend>
        <p class="estilo">_____________________________</p>

        <P class="estilo">
            ¿Esta seguro de preincribirte al curso de @Model.Curso.NombreCurso? @Model.Curso.Num 
        </P>
        <p class="estilo">_____________________________</p>
        <br />
    </fieldset>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btnBgColor text-white">Aceptar</button>

    </div>
 
</form>
```

**And these are the functions I use in Javascript to make color and text changes.**

```
function myFunction2() {

    var btn = document.getElementById("myButtonChangeF");

    if (btn.value == "Preinscribirse") {
        btn.value = "Anular";
        btn.innerHTML = "Anular";
        btn.setAttribute("style", "background: linear-gradient(135deg, #24309d, #96989A);");


    }
    else {
        btn.value = "Preinscribirse";
        btn.innerHTML = "Preinscribirse";
        btn.setAttribute("style", "background: linear-gradient(135deg, #9d2449, #96989A);");
    }
}
```

*I’d appreciate your support!*

Comment: I recommend dropping your code into a [codepen](https://codepen.io)

Answer (score 0):

Struggling to find what you are stuck on here...
In order to store which courses the user has enrolled in you are going to need [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in your javascript.